# Connect to Gmail with PHP & IMAP

Tags: php, ssl, gmail, imap

I have enabled `OpenSSL` and `IMAP` functions from my `php.ini` file and `phpinfo()` confirms it.

By using the code below i can connect to a Hotmail account but not to a Gmail account.(of course i change the `$connect_to` to point to Hotmail.)

```
$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$connection = imap_open($connect_to, $user, $password)
  or die("Can't connect to '$connect_to': " . imap_last_error());
imap_close($connection);
```

The returned error is

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webmail_client_practise/index.php on line 6
Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX': Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Notice: Unknown: Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Unfortunately i cannot find a complete tutorial of how to use the IMAP functions.

Any ideas, solutions or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You missed "{"
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

Comment: I was going to ask if you can access any other folder other than INBOX

Comment: I have updated the post with the new error, @SarDauMort - Thank you, i have edited my error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After searching for my problem on the Internet, i did not found a solution that solves my problem completely. Although if

1) I use the insecure `$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';`

2)And allow gmail to be accessed by `less secured apps`,

solves my problem for now.

Please check this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: less secured apps no longer works, but using app passwords will allow you to still use a password just not the account password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

If you get blocked, this can be because google sees a login from a new device.

Go to your google account and check 
https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity 
and let them know the 'Unknown device is ok to use'.

Comment: And in my case: turn on 'Unsave apps allowed' at https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/lesssecureapps?pageId=none

Comment: This did it for me - thanks. Although not sure why I couldn't find that link you posted!

Comment: In my case the link still works, but you have to be logged in. It's possible that it depends on other settings in your account, so just try to find the 'Unsave apps allowed'

Answer (score 1):

First check your date and time settings on your server are correct.

Alternatively try:

```
$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
```

This will stop it from trying to validate certificate.

I will probably get downvotes from people telling me this is bad practice as this leaves you open to Man in the Middle attacks. Which is true.

Comment: Haha! Yes i know! `Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com::993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webmail_client_practise/index.php on line 6
Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com::993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX': Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com::993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid remote specification
Notice: Unknown: Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com::993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid remote specification (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0` this is my new error

Comment: You have put two colons...Or I have in my answer @Makis, sorry!

Comment: and goes on... `Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webmail_client_practise/index.php on line 6
Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX': Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
...........

Comment: At least now it is correctly talking to the gmail server and attempting to authenticate.

Comment: I think you need to go to: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha This Google now being extra protective...