# imap connection issue using ddeboer/imap

Tags: imap

I was trying to fetch mails from my gmail account using ddeboer/imap

```
$server = new Server('imap.gmail.com');
$connection = $server->authenticate('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx');
$mailbox = $connection->getMailbox('INBOX');
$messages = $mailbox->getMessages();
```

But $connection variable to showing error due to this I can't able to connect to my account.
Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222250/connect-to-gmail-with-php-imap  . To which Port are you connecting? Port Number is missing.

Comment: Thanks Sammer, Its default 993, i need a solution using ddeboer/imap library

Comment: Add tags to question accordingly. Also show errors.

Comment: I can't figure out the error, as nothing is showing in the console.Basically the problem is  imap_open  is not working