# Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection refused

Tags: php, gmail-api

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'mail@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

He constantly writes that access is denied. The feeling of being closed by Google security. Where to allow access for no message:

> Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com, 993: Connection refused

Website https://pomidor.cc

Answer (score 0):

Something on your network -- possibly a firewall -- is blocking your connection to the Google mail server. Contact your system administrator or hosting provider for details.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, it looks like a problem related with a missing certificate on your end. Here are a couple of questions with workarounds/solutions [1][2].

You may also consider to start using the Gmail API which allows you to do several actions in a simple way. You can enable the IMAP setting [3] and set the quickstart so you can start making requests from there [4].

[1] [Connect to Gmail with PHP & IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222250)

[2] [Certificate error using IMAP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891729)

[3] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateImap

[4] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution are in Host Firewall. If you have acess to **WHM** check:

addon_hgfirewall.cgi

Put the 993 port in "Inbound Ports"
Put the 993 port in "Outbound Ports"

That's all.

[See in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avcaN.png)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and what solved it for me was 2 things:

1. I used my own password instead of the app password which you can
   generate [here](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security)
2. Instead of `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX` i used 
   `{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX`